# Leaving out Margin Values vs Explicitly Having Them

Tags: css

If you leave certain margin values unspecified (`top, right, bottom or left`), is it the same as explicitly marking them as `0`?

For example, in my code base I saw the following:

`margin: 30px 0 0 0`

I figured that I could instead just refactor this as:

`margin-top: 30px`

Are these equivalent? Nothing has changed on my page stylistically.

Thanks

Comment: It's not 0 by default so no. Nothing has changed because you probably have * {margin: 0} ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify them, they keep the default values if they had any, for example:

An `<h1>` has `margin-top:21.44px`,`margin-bottom:21.44px`

Now if you set it's margins like this `margin: 30px 0 0 0` the top will be 30px and the reste gonna become 0px as you would expect.

[image]

but the other way around would be :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No it is not the same.

If do not specify margin value it has default value.

If you do specify it has the value that you assigned.

In your case probably this element has `margin: 0` anyway. But not always will it be the same.

Example:

```css
.no-margin {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>This has default margin top and bottom</h1>

<h1 class="no-margin"> This one has margin set to 0</h1>
```

To see the difference open devtools and check those two elements.

Comment: If both make my page look/behave the same way, are there any other gotchas I should be aware of I remove the explicit `0` ?

Comment: It depends in an element. Some, like `div` has default margin 0, but other like `h1` has default margin more than 0. So it is always a good idea to set margin exactly the way you would like it to be. It is easier not to make a mistake that way.

Answer (score 1):

Each specific margin attribute (as well as other attributes as padding for instance) could be expressed as one expression:

```
margin: 10px 20px 30px 40px
```

is equivalent to:

```
margin-top: 10px; 
margin-right: 20px; 
margin-bottom: 30px; 
margin-left: 40px;
```

As described in MDN WebDocs:

- When one value is specified, it applies the same margin to all four
  sides.
- When two values are specified, the first margin applies to the
  top and bottom, the second to the left and right.
- When three values
  are specified, the first margin applies to the top, the second to the
  left and right, the third to the bottom.
- When four values are
  specified, the margins apply to the top, right, bottom, and left in
  that order (clockwise).

Related to **zero values**, the default margin value is not zero, so you should specify it, if not **no default value is applied** as you can see in the snippet

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#zeroMargin {
  margin: 0;
}

#someMargin {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#fullMargin {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="noMargin">
</div>

<div id="zeroMargin">
</div>

<div id="someMargin">
</div>

<div id="fullMargin">
</div>
```